# How to use this 5 and a half width windshield?

Tags: part-identification

I recently went to [Legoland in the Boston](https://boston.legolanddiscoverycenter.com/) area and found the following windshield brick in the free build section.

[image: build photo]

Ignore my airplane build of questionable quality. What puzzled me was the width of the windshield piece I found in the part bin. As you can see it was roughly 5 and a half bricks wide. At the time I was confused at how the brick was intended to be used. Upon reflection my best guess is it might have fit if I would have used a 2x1 brick with the single center top bump on one side.

[image: Another view]

I couldn't make out the part number but I was able to barely discern it was a Lego branded part. The part number was in the center section of the windshield. I'd be interested to see a picture of the brick used in a custom build or an original set so I can see what others have done with it or how the designers intended it to be used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That part is a little tough to use on its own. It is generally paired with another element to create a [6-wide windscreen (6567c02)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=102989):

[image: 6567c02]

Without the outer part, you don't have any nice stud connections to work with, and as you mentioned the size is strange, so it would be challenging to work it into a build.

I imagine it is now obvious how this is used, but since you asked to see this in a set, here is one example:

[image: 60007 High Speed Chase]

Comment: That explains a lot. Someone must have popped it out of the frame. I bet if I knew what I was looking for I could have scrounged up the frame in one of the bins.